# A question on curves on a hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a hypersurface of degree $r$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and $Z\subset X$ be a closed subscheme of pure dim 1. Let $g(Z):=1-\chi(\mathcal{O}_Z)$ and $d(Z)$ be its degree. I'm wondering that is there any bound $g(Z)\leq F_{r,n}(d(Z))$ where $F_{r,n}(-)$ is a degree two polynomial?

When $Z$ is irreducible and reduced, I think this follows from some classical results of curves in $\mathbb{P}^n$. But what will happen when $Z$ is reducible, or even non-reduced?

The main example I consider is a degree five smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Comment: I do not quite understand this question.  For $n\geq 4$, it is quite possible for such a hypersurface to contain, for every integer  $g\gg 0$, a degree-$2$, nonreduced curve $Z$ whose reduced scheme is a line and whose nilradical is an invertible sheaf on that line of degree $-g-1$.  Do you want to assume that $Z$ is reduced?

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! Does this example exist on quintic 3fold? The main example I am considering is quintic 3fold, and I find such inequality for all closed subschemes of dim 1(possibly non-reduced) will be really useful. But I did not find this in books or papers. Maybe it is well-known that one can get a bound of $g$ by $F(d)$ for all one-dimensional closed subschemes, using the results for integral curves?

Comment: I said something wrong in my previous comment.  There is a quadratic bound for all reduced curves.

Answer (score 1):

For a reduced curve $Z$, a general linear projection from $Z$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a birational morphism to a plane curve $C$ of degree $d=d(Z)$.  Thus, $$1-\chi(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z) \leq 1-\chi(C,\mathcal{O}_C) = d(d-2)/2.$$  In general, this is the best possible inequality, since some hypersurfaces of degree $r$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ contain a $2$-plane, and thus contain plane curves $C$ of degree $d$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am also wondering that is it possible to bound $g$ by $d$ of $C$, when $C$ is on a normal quintic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (possibly singular)?

Comment: The argument in my answer applies to all hypersurfaces (singular or not) of every degree in every projective space of dimension at least $3$.